# Function to get list of all identifiers in String Template (Python)

Tags: python, stringtemplate

For standard library `string template` in Python, is there a function to get a list of all identifiers?

For example, with the following xml file:

```
<Text>Question ${PrimaryKey}:</Text>
<Text>Cheat: ${orientation}</Text>
```

the function will return something like `PrimaryKey, orientation`

Comment: So you want to search for all occurrences of ${something} in a xml file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [string.Formatter.parse](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#string.Formatter.parse)

```
from string import Formatter

s="""<Text>Question ${PrimaryKey}:</Text>
<Text>Cheat: ${orientation}</Text>"""


print([ele[1] for ele in Formatter().parse(s) if ele[1]])
['PrimaryKey', 'orientation']
```

Comment: This worked! So is it the square brackets around the phrase that generate a list of ele[1]?

Comment: @YunCHan, it extracts the second element which is the placeholder name, if you `print(list(Formatter().parse(s)))` you will see it returns tuples  which hold different elements, `[('<Text>Question $', 'PrimaryKey', '', None), (':</Text>\n<Text>Cheat: $', 'orientation', '', None), ('</Text>', None, None, None)]`

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.11+

A method called [get_identifiers()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Template.get_identifiers) should help

```py
from string import Template

s="""<Text>Question ${PrimaryKey}:</Text>
<Text>Cheat: ${orientation}</Text>"""
temp = Template(s)
print(temp.get_identifiers())
```

Returns

```
['PrimaryKey', 'orientation']
```

Otherwise [solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30418220/13224210) works well.